# How can I implement a remove function to this custom C++ List class?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, templates

I have a custom list called *myList*, which works like this:

```
// creating and adding:
myList<int> numbers;
numbers.add(10);
numbers.add(20);

// listing each item:
int n
while (numbers.nextItems(n)) {
        std::cout << m;
}
```

And here's the source code of *myList:*

```
template<class T>
class myList
{

    struct eachItem
    {
        T  data;
        eachItem *nextItem;

        eachItem(eachItem *p = NULL)
        {
            nextItem = p;
        }

    }; // end of eachItem

    eachItem *beginning;
    eachItem *current;

    myList(const myList&);

public:
    myList()
    {
        current = beginning = new eachItem;
    }

    void add(const T& dat);
    bool nextItems(T& dat);

    ~myList();
};


template <class T>
myList<T>::~myList()
{
    eachItem *p;
    while ((p = beginning) != NULL)
    {
        beginning = p->nextItem;
        delete p;
    }
}

template <class T>
void myList<T>::add(const T& dat)
{
    eachItem *eachI;

    for (eachI = beginning; eachI->nextItem != NULL; eachI = eachI->nextItem);

    eachItem *newList = new eachItem(*eachI);

    eachI->data = dat;

    eachI->nextItem = newList;
}

template <class T>
bool myList<T>::nextItems(T& dat)
{

    if (current->nextItem == NULL)
    {
        current = beginning;

        return(false);
    }

    dat = current->data;


    current = current->nextItem;

    return(true);
}
```

Now, I would like to add a remove functionality to this custom list class. I would like it to work like this:

```
numbers.remove(10)
```

I had many different tries, but I couldn't get it work.

Here's my attempt:

```
template <class T>
void myList<T>::remove(const T& dat)
{
    eachItem *eachI;

    for (eachI = beginning; eachI->nextItem != dat; eachI = eachI->nextItem);

    eachItem *newList = new eachItem(*eachI);
    eachI->nextItem = newList;


    eachItem *eachI2; // from the deleted to the actual end

    for (eachI2 = eachI->nextItem; eachI2->nextItem != NULL; eachI2 = eachI2->nextItem);

    eachItem *newList2 = new eachItem(*eachI2);
    eachI2->nextItem = newList2;
}
```

Comment: Show your attempts and explain what the issues are with them

Comment: Also please format your code - there is no need for this much whitespace between each line of code (makes it harder to read)

Comment: sorry, the original variable type isn't int, I just changed it to int to make it simpler, I deleted the deleting part, sorry

Comment: Show your "Not Working" remove code.

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: A function that's supposed to remove something and contains `new` (twice, even) looks fishy.

Comment: You forgot to say what `numbers.remove(10)` is supposed to do. Should it remove the tenth element, or the first ten elements, or the first `10`, or all `10`s, or something else?

Comment: it should remove the element which has a value of 10

Comment: @MartonZeisler Your list can contain several. Remove all of them or one of them? If just one, which one?

Comment: Just one, no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your for loop condition should be  `eachI->nextItem->data!=dat` so that you compare data, instead you were comparing address of next node and data

```
void myList<T>::remove(const T& dat)
{
    //Special acse for deleting first node
    if(beginning!=NULL && beginning->data==dat)
    {
        eachItem *toDelete = beginning;
        beginning = beginning->nextItem;
        current = beginning;
        delete toDelete;
        return;
    }
    eachItem *eachI;

    for (eachI = beginning;eachI!=NULL && eachI->nextItem->data != dat; eachI = eachI->nextItem);
    //if eachI=NULL then data to be deleted is not found
    if(eachI==NULL)
    {
        cout<<dat<<" not found in this list, so not deleted\n";
        return;   //no further processing required.
    }

    //After this for eachI->nextItem will point to node that is to be deleted
    eachItem *toDelete = eachI->nextItem;
    //now remove link between eachI and toDelete
    //i.e. let eachI->next point to toDelete->nextItem
    eachI->nextItem = toDelete->nextItem;
    //Therefore skipping toDelete
    //Now tieing up loose ends(delete the node)
    delete toDelete;

}
```

Also change your add function

```
void myList<T>::add(const T& dat)
{

    if(beginning==NULL)
    {
        beginning = new eachItem;
        current=beginning;
        beginning->data = dat;
        return;
    }
    eachItem *eachI;
    for (eachI = beginning;eachI->nextItem != NULL; eachI = eachI->nextItem);
    eachItem *newList = new eachItem;

    newList->data = dat;

    eachI->nextItem = newList;
    newList->nextItem = NULL;
}
```

And your constructor too

```
myList()
{
    current = beginning = NULL;
}
```

main function and output

```
int main()
{
    myList<int> numbers;
    numbers.add(10);
    numbers.add(20);
    numbers.add(30);
    numbers.add(40);
    int m;
    while (numbers.nextItems(m)) {
        std::cout << m;
    }
cout<<"\n";
    numbers.remove(10);
    while (numbers.nextItems(m)) {
        std::cout << m;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    numbers.remove(30);
    while (numbers.nextItems(m)) {
        std::cout << m;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> OUTPUT
>       10203040
>       203040
>       2040

I dont see where does it `stucks in loop forever`

Comment: could you please your edit note into your code? I'm just confused a little bit.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that it doesn't work if I'm trying to delete the first item in the list, like this:
`code
         myList<int>numbers;
         numbers.add(10);
         numbers.add(20);
         numbers.add(30);

         numbers.remove(10); `

Comment: You need to check that `eachI->nextItem` isn't null before you do `eachI->nextItem->data`.

Comment: Added special case. Mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: thanks, but now the program crashes, it loads all sorts of numbers forever, it's in a stuck forever loop now if i try to remove the first item

Comment: Which `loop` does it stuck in?

Comment: In the first for loop in your code. But it only gets stuck if I am trying to remove the first element. Other than that it works

Comment: @MartonZeisler Edited all functions, now working correctly